# How to make two elements be at the same "depth" in the DOM?

Tags: html, css, dom

It seems impossible to make two elements render parallel to each other on the z axis. In other words, if I were to turn my website sideways, I could never see two of them on the same depth level; even elements with the same `z-index` are treated as being on different levels based on their order in the DOM.

This is a problem, because sometimes I need to render two nearby elements with box shadow, and as part of the design they should be at the same level, not casting the shadow onto each other, but on elements beneath them.

Why is this the case? What's to keep the browser from rendering two elements with the same `z-index` at the same level? Furthermore, is there a solution or workaround for this problem?

Right now I'm developing a site where this is an issue. For example, see this design, where 2 boxes (box containing genre/comments and box containing the votes / title) are floating next to each other with a small space between them, but are part of the same group, and should not cast box shadow onto each other, as neither should be higher or lower:

[image]

Comment: don't think you should try and figure out why no elements can be at the same "depth", instead share some of your relevant code and i'm sure many people here will be able to help you out; the way you're asking it's too generic...

Comment: I agree with @webeno. I can't really think of a good scenario with box-shadow where I would need that. Either one of two elements is on top of the other or, if they both need to cast a shadow on other elements, I would group them in a parent element and assign the shadow to that.

Comment: @webeno does the example help?

Comment: From a design standpoint, I wouldn't add a shadow in your example, but that's personal taste. Also, there's no shadow in your picture, but I believe, this is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gardbfka/1/

Comment: *Consider this scenario*: when the two elements collide, do they intertwine? Do they crumple into each other like the crumple zones of two cars? ... That is why two elements can NEVER be at the exact same z-index.

Comment: @myfunkyside Right, that's what I thought of as well. Box-shadow might be reasonable at some point, what happens to two text elements on the exact same depth? Therefore, I guess it's a technical restriction of rendering engines.

Comment: Useful: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: @Paul I probably agree with you; it was a thought during the design that reminded me of the issue though, so I brought it up sooner rather than later. Problem solved either with my self answer or top answer provided.

Comment: Okay, I have to correct myself.. the crumple zone was a bad analogy, 'cause that suggests they collide on the x- or y-axis... **But consider this**: being placed at the exact same position, how would two elements at the same depth behave? Do they break into pixels and form a pixel-mash-up of both elements put together? Are the color and alpha values of each pixel of both elements combined? Think of them as paper sheets - the only way you would get two sheets at the same depth, is by pressing them together so hard they become one... There is just no room for two elements at the same z-index.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an inner wrapper block element with desired background color.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col pull-left">xxx</div>
        <div class="col pull-right">yyy</div>
    </div>
</div>

.col{
    width:50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #222;
}
```

In this case, applying box-shadow to `div.col` will make one block's shadow area over the other as you mentioned. (`.pull-left` and `.pull-right` is from Bootstrap, just floating effect).

By doing this,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col pull-left"><div class="wrapper">xxx</div></div>
        <div class="col pull-right"><div class="wrapper">yyy</div></div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
    background:#fff;
}
```

You can see the overlapped shadow is covered by the inserted `div.wrapper`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzakradd/1/) here.

Comment: The two elements need to be slightly separate.

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer Do you mean there is a small gap? That doesn't matter (actually better to avoid overlapped shadow). See http://jsfiddle.net/Lzakradd/2/

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer Or if you mean the gap should be clear (without shadow), then just apply the box-shadow to the parent box, i.e., div.row in my example.

Comment: @mrmoment: Nice solution, http://jsfiddle.net/Lzakradd/3/ might even illustrate it better.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of a trick to do this:

Create duplicate element of each element that needs a box shadow and position the duplicates at a lower z-index than the elements that should appear to have the shadows.

```css
#depth_higher{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
}
#depth_lower{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
#foo, #bar{
  background-color:green;
  margin:7px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
#foo_shadow, #bar_shadow{
  box-shadow:0px 0px 50px 0px #000;
  margin:7px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="depth_higher">
  <div id="foo"></div>
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
<div id="depth_lower">
  <div id="foo_shadow"></div>
  <div id="bar_shadow"></div>
</div>
```